# how can i truncate item inside double brackets shopify

Tags: html, shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I need to truncate the amount of characters that is returned from the title of each product but the file where this change needs to be applied has a set of double brackets wrapped around the specific element that needs truncating (see code)

```html
<div class="boost-pfs-filter-product-bottom">
                <a href="[[itemUrl]]" class="boost-pfs-filter-product-item-title">
                    <h4 class="cl-product-card-name">[[itemTitle]]</h4>
                </a>
                <div class="cl-product-card-price">[[itemPrice]]</div>
                
                <button class="quick-add-btn" [[quickAddAttr]] onclick='window.blubolt.quickadd.open("[[productHandle]]",  {"stockMap": "{}" })'>
                    [[quickAddText]]
                </button>
            </div>
```

The element that needs truncating is [[itemTitle]] on line 3, but i am not sure how to go about this as the double square brackets is causing issues. Any ideas what is needed to be done here? If any more info is needed feel free to ask

[image: picture1]

Comment: I would recommend using [CSS text-overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) to truncate the text based on available space. This makes responsive behaviour possible.

Comment: If not, beware that the double brackets are marking a variable. This way liquid can know what is HTML or static content, and what should be filled from the database. Template languages like Liquid also have a concept of filters, where you can apply some function on that value like [truncate](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/truncate/): `[[ itemTitle | truncate: 20 ]]`. CSS is way more flexible, though.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion Andy, however i need to be able to add a setting inside the clients theme so the client can set how many characters they want to truncate by, so it needs to be liquid (I believe)

Comment: @Andy i have tried out '[[ itemTitle | truncate: 20 ]]' but the truncate filter does not work withtin these square brackets

Comment: Have you tried curly brackets? `{{ itemTitle | truncate: 20 }}`. Sorry, I’m not familiar with liquid’s specific syntax.

Comment: yeahh, I have added an image of what the response is when using ur initial answer, and when i change to curly brackets nothing shows up at all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245620/discussion-between-andy-and-jackt180).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
<div class="boost-pfs-filter-product-bottom">
            <a href="[[itemUrl]]" class="boost-pfs-filter-product-item-title">
                <h4 class="cl-product-card-name" aria-label="[[itemTitle]]" title="[[itemTitle]]">[[itemTitle | truncate: 20]]</h4>
            </a>
            <div class="cl-product-card-price">[[itemPrice]]</div>
            
            <button class="quick-add-btn" [[quickAddAttr]] onclick='window.blubolt.quickadd.open("[[productHandle]]",  {"stockMap": "{}" })' aria-label="[[quickAddText]] [[itemTitle]]">
                [[quickAddText]]
            </button>
        </div>
```

Anything with a pipe `|` inside a variable will apply a filter, in this case the [truncate filter](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/truncate/). Filters are functions available in the Liquid language that allow transforming the variable value.

In my example, please note also

`aria-label` is still including the full title because it will render the very important heading and link outline more helpful for people with disabilities. CSS truncation would render this unnecessary.

`title` also includes the full title, which gives mouse users a way to expand the title by hovering on it.

`aria-label` for the button is helpful for screen reader users who navigate by means of tab. Otherwise, all Quick Add buttons have the same accessible name.